# How to selected and item from Entity and insert the item in other table having same structure using c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, linq-to-entities

I am fetching an item from one table and inserting into other table having same table structure how to do using `LINQ` to entity in `C#`?

```
public static void GetInfillIDAndInsertIntoInfillPO(int infillID)
{
    Entities db = new Entities();
    List<Infill> infillitem = (from c in db.Infills
                                    where (c.InfillID == infillID)
                                    select c).ToList();

    List<InfillPO> infillPO = new List<InfillPO>();

    db.InfillPOes.Add(infillitem);

}
```

Here `Infill` and `InfillPO` have same table structure. Just the `InfillPO` doesn't contain the `Primary key`. Now, i just want to insert the record as it is in `InfillPO` table.

**I have also tried it by casting. but wont work.**

```
public static void GetInfillIDAndInsertIntoInfillPO(int infillID)
{
    XtremeProcurementEntities db = new XtremeProcurementEntities();
    Infill infillitem = (from c in db.Infills
                                where (c.InfillID == infillID)
                                select c).FirstOrDefault();

    InfillPO infillPO = new InfillPO();

    db.InfillPOes.Add((infillPO)infillitem);                
}
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You make a select of Type T1 from the Table and select it into T2. This T2 you can then add to the context and save it.

```
List<InfillPO> infillitem = (from c in db.Infills
                                       where (c.InfillID == infillID)
                                               select new InfillPO
                             {
                                  PropertyA = c.PropertyA
                             }).ToList();
```

This would be the easiest and fastest solution. Depends if you want to change the Columns frequently...

Comment: m not getting you!want to insert the record as it is in InfillPO from Infill table! Please clarify and you code doesnt work what is PropertyA m new to LINQ so please...!